# ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4500 - Support OpenCL or not?

Tags: gpu, ati-mobility-radeon, gpgpu

I wanted to run Folding@Home on my laptop.
I downloaded version 6.41 which supports GPGPU for ATI with the r_700 switch.
It seemd too work slow so I took a look with GPU-Z and I was puzzled.

ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4500 - Support OpenCL or not?

I thought it does but according to GPU-Z it doesn't.
Can anyone clear things for me?

[image: GPU-Z]

Answer (score 5):

It does support OpenCL. I have same GPU in my HP laptop.

This is how to get OpenCL support:

1. Download AMD app SDK short for AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing (APP) SDK (formerly ATI Stream) you get it from [here](http://developer.amd.com/tools/hc/AMDAPPSDK/Pages/default.aspx)
2. Supported drivers are available [here](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx)
3. Download and install your driver using the latest Catalyst driver installer for your GPU device

After that is done your device should support OpenCL. To check if it worked, use GPU-Z or GPU caps viewer.

Comment: Hi! I'm having problems in finding a Driver that supports OpenCL. Is there a way to find out which drivers have OpenCL without installing them? BTW. Is there a Windows Server 2016 driver?